# How to store and lookup data, based on multiple xml attributes?

Tags: c#, linq, list, lookup

I am querying an xml file and returning 3 attributes per selection (each entry that meets my criteria will return 3 attributes details). I need to store these values, and then later look up the first attribute, and return the 2 other stored attributes related to it.

```
var items = from item in doc.Descendants("SUM")
                        select new
                        {                                    
                            id = (string)item.Attribute("id"),
                            category = (string)item.Attribute("cat"),
                            selection = (string)item.Attribute("sel")
                        };
```

The above code returns 3 attributes per *item* found. I need to store those 3 entries so they are associated together, then later perform a lookup on the stored entries. So example, I need to be able to look up a stored value of id=1, and return the corresponding category and selection entry.

I was researching the Lookup method of C# but don't understand how to use it. List's seem like they might work, but I don't know how to store multiple pieces of data into an entry in a list (maybe concatenate into a single entry, but then I'm not sure about performing the lookup on it). Any suggestions regarding how to do this with a LIST or LOOKUP (or other unmentioned way) are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) (or other options, such as [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx), etc)to filter this further:

```
var items = from item in doc.Descendants("SUM")
                    select new
                    {                                    
                        Id = (string)item.Attribute("id"),
                        Category = (string)item.Attribute("cat"),
                        Selection = (string)item.Attribute("sel")
                    };

var filtered = items.Where(i => i.Id == 1);

// Then use these as needed
foreach(var item in filtered)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cat: {0}, Sel: {1}", item.Category, item.Selection);
}
```

The `ToLookup` method actually serves a very different purpose.  It builds a data structure  which implements [`ILookup<T,U>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291.aspx), which is a lookup table where you can easily return all of the items that match a specific key.  This is useful if you're going to perform many lookups from your data, but not if you just want to "lookup" items matching a single value.

Answer (score 2):

First step is to create a class to store the data:

```
public class Item // come up with a better name...
{
    public string ID {get; set;}
    public string Catagory {get; set;}
    public string Selection {get; set;}
}
```

Second, if your lookups are *always* by `ID`, you could store the collection in a `Dictionary<string, Item>` and to lookups with the indexer property:

```
// add
var dict = (from item in doc.Descendants("SUM")
            select new  Item
            {                                    
                ID = (string)item.Attribute("id"),
                Category = (string)item.Attribute("cat"),
                Selection = (string)item.Attribute("sel")
            })
            .ToDictionary(i=>i.ID, i=>i);
// lookup
Item foundItem = dict[lookupID];
```

If your lookups need to be more generic then just store them in a `List<Item>` and do lookups with Linq and lambda functions:

```
List<Item> myList = new List<Item>();

// add items
List.Add(item);

// lookup one
Item item = myList.Single(i => i.ID == lookupID);
// lookup many
var items = myList.Where(i => i.Category == lookupCategory);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would probably want a real type to select into:

```cs
public class Item 
{                                    
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string selection { get; set; }
};
```

Then you can do some things like

```cs
IEnumberable<Item> items = from item in doc.Descendants("SUM")
                    select new
                    {                                    
                        id = (string)item.Attribute("id"),
                        category = (string)item.Attribute("cat"),
                        selection = (string)item.Attribute("sel")
                    };

Item itemIWant = items.Where(item => item.id == "someIdNumber")
                      .FirstOrDefault();
if (itemIWant != null)
{
     // do stuff with itemIWant.category and itemIWant.selection
}
```

or if there are multiple matches

```cs
IEnumberable<Item> itemsICareAbout = 
      items.Where(item => item.id == "someIdNumber');
foreach(Item item in itemsICareAbout)
{
     // do stuff for each item
}
```